# Finding an Antiderivative for an Exact Form

Tags: integration, differential-forms

Let $\omega$ be an exact $1$-form on a path-connected manifold $M$. For a fixed $x \in M$ we can define for all $y \in M$.
$$
g(y) := \int_\gamma \gamma^*(\omega),
$$
where $\gamma$ is a path from $x$ to $y$.  Because $\omega$ is exact, it is independent of $\gamma$. What I want to show is that $dg = \omega$. My thought is that
$$
d\left( \int_\gamma \gamma^*(\omega) \right) = \int d(\omega(\gamma)),
$$
because $d$ commutes with integration, and $\gamma^*(\omega)$ is defined to be $\omega(\gamma(t))$. Then
$$
d(\omega(\gamma)) = d\omega(\gamma) \cdot d\gamma
$$
by chain rule. By change of variable, we get
$$
\int d \omega = \omega.
$$
But, someone pointed out that $d\omega = 0$ by exactness. My thought is that this is only true when integrating over closed paths. What's going on? Thanks.

Edit: Another thought is that $d(\omega)$ and $d\omega$ are two different things. So, that $d(\omega) = 0$, but $d\omega$ is a element of the cotangent bundle. Thus, $d\omega$ is not $0$.

Comment: Have you tried to write it in a more classical way like $\int_x^y F(z) \, dz$?

Comment: $\int_\gamma \gamma^*(\omega)$ is wrong anyways as I understand the notation. Presumably $\int_\gamma \omega$ or $\int_0^1 \gamma^*(\omega)$ was meant. (assuming paths go from 0 to 1 in the domain)

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. But, I need a rigorous argument that it works when we have exact $1$-forms. This isn't homework. I'm trying to help some students with their qualifying exams.

Comment: I meant that you should not just do it in a classical way, but rewrite every expression of your post in a classical way to see what is happening, where you do something incorrect.

Comment: @md2perpe If $F'(z) = f(z)$, then $\int_x^y f(z) \, dz$ would differentiate, with respect to $y$ as $f(y)$. But, it wouldn't make sense to move the derivative inside, as $f$ is not a function of $y$. Correct? But, I still don't see how to fix my work.

Comment: You could write it as $\int_0^1 f(z(t)) \, z'(t) \, dt$ where $z(0) = x$ and $z(1) = y.$

Comment: @md2perpe Yes.  Thank you for helping so much.  If you copy and paste as an answer, I will upvote and select.